# How to Display fetched data from Firestore in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I'm a newbie in Flutter.
I have stored data in firestore in nested collections as you can see here[Firestore1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OekG6.png) and here[Firestore2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MKiyQ.png).

I wrote code for that as below:

```
  class Timeline extends StatefulWidget {
 @override
  _TimelineState createState() => _TimelineState();
   }

  class _TimelineState extends State<Timeline>
   with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin<Timeline> {
   final eventref = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('event');

  final slider = SleekCircularSlider(
   appearance: CircularSliderAppearance(
  spinnerMode: true,
  size: 50.0,
 ));
   List<EventCard> event = [];
   getEvents() async {

     print(user.uid);
    QuerySnapshot snapshot =
    await eventref.doc(user.uid).collection('post').limit(2).get();

  List<EventCard> event = [];
  snapshot.docs.forEach((doc) {
  print('this is doc ------');
  print(doc);
  event.add(EventCard.fromMap(doc.data()));
  });
   return event;

  }

    @override
   bool get wantKeepAlive => true;

     @override
   Widget build(context) {
    return Scaffold(
   body: Container(
      child: FutureBuilder(
    future: getEvents(),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (!snapshot.hasData) {
        return slider;
      }
      print('reached here:${snapshot.data}');
      return ListView(
        children: snapshot.data,
      );
      },
      )),
      );
      }
      }

class EventCard extends StatelessWidget {
final String id;
final String event;
final String organiser;
final String description;
final String date;
final String startTime;

EventCard({
this.id,
this.event,
this.organiser,
this.description,
this.date,
this.startTime,
});

factory EventCard.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> doc) {
return EventCard(
  id: doc['id'],
  event: doc['Event'],
  organiser: doc['Organiser'],
  description: doc['Description'],
  date: doc['Date'],
  startTime: doc['Start Time'],
);
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Container(
  child: Text('Done'),
);
}
}
```

Sorry for long code, but only response i'm getting with this is here [Debug Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a05h4.png)
I tried to make 'EventCard' without build method as i saw in a tutorial online, but here it show error 'No concrete implementation of EventCard'

Any help? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Instead of `snapshot.data`, use `snapshot.data()`

Comment: snapshot.data is in context of Future not of Firestore. I haven't seen `factory` within a stateless widget. Maybe it is worth while to segregate your data class with the `factory` from the stateless widget.